# How do I recursively list the contents of all files in a repository (extension-agnostic) into a single text file?

Tags: linux, bash, ls

I know that using "ls -R ." in bash you can recursively list the filenames.

Can I use some similar command to list the contents of each file just the way their names are displayed using the ls command. I mean to a single file or stream like the standard output.

Is there a way I can format the output from such a command? Like say, add something like a few blank lines between the contents of each of the files for better readbility?

Answer (score 1):

Still a relevant question I stumbled upon so I built a litle script for this, avoiding the actual output-file being processed and well, it works in 2023.

```
output_file="targetfile.txt"

# Remove the output file if it already exists to avoid including it in the search
if [ -e "$output_file" ]; then
  rm "$output_file"
fi

find . -type f | while read -r file; do
  # Skip the output file if it accidentally gets included in the search
  if [ "$file" = "./$output_file" ]; then
    continue
  fi

  # Output file path
  echo "$file"

  # Output file contents
  cat "$file"

  # Output new line as a separator
  echo
  echo
done > "$output_file"
```

This script first checks if the targetfile.txt exists in the current directory and removes it before running the find command. Then, it checks each file during the loop and skips the targetfile.txt if it's accidentally included in the search. This way, the output file won't be included in the results.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f | while read file;
do
  # Here you can do whatever you like
  # Like output a few empty lines
  echo
  echo

  # output filename
  echo $file      
  # this prints the contents of the file to STD OUT
  cat $file;

done > targetfile
```

Comment: But how do you get everything into a single file? When I tried this, it would go into an endless loop, `cat`ing the same files all over again.

Comment: @slhck - looping? I dont see how

Comment: How do I use this: find . -type f -exec cat {} \; to put it into a single file?

Comment: @Arpith - `find . -type f -exec cat {} \; > /path/to/your/outputfile`

Comment: @Nifle: I think the command is listing the same files' contents recursively rather than going in depth through the filesystem heirarchy and listing the contents of various files.

Comment: This simply does not work if the output file is in the same directory, see this pastie for an example: http://pastie.org/4400270

Comment: @slhck - weird..

Comment: @ slhck: I know. cat throws a warning saying the input file is same as the output file. And in most cases the file, the user would find i convenient to have the file in the same directory as that in which the command is to be run. Is there a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

Create a meta-script with find and pipe it to sh.

```
$ find /home/jaroslav/tmp/su/  2>/dev/null \
    -printf 'echo -e \\\\n\\\\n%p\ncat "%p"\n' |sh
```

out:

```
/home/jaroslav/tmp/su/
cat: /home/jaroslav/tmp/su/: Is a directory


/home/jaroslav/tmp/su/diff.tar.gz
J▒▒P▒▒M
6▒M)FR▒▒▒▒▒▒F2▒/9▒e▒▒s]▒N▒h▒▒ޫzr▒▒hD▒▒Z&▒▒X▒▒|*▒o▒▒z▒▒▒▒|x߁▒▒E▒▒▒4▒▒Kऺ▒▒J▒-▒B▒▒▒Z▒▒▒?▒▒▒▒▒
        ▒▒P▒▒鿶▒▒JF▒j▒=Z▒?%▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒{▒▒▒M▒▒▒▒$▒▒q(

/home/jaroslav/tmp/su/while
while read line; do
    login=$(echo $line | cut -d : -f 1)
        echo $login
done < /etc/passwd
```